# AngularJS -- Toggle class for only one element (ng-class and ng-click)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I'm trying to apply a class to only one element at a time ([see this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiNY999Rp7WouyLb1MHw?p=preview)).

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in listItems">
    <a ng-class="{'userActive': isActive, 'userInactive': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">L</a>
    <a ng-class="{'userActive': isActive, 'userInactive': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">R</a>
    <a ng-class="{'userActive': isActive, 'userInactive': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">J</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.listItems = [{description: 'item1', number: 1}];
});
```

Right now, when I click an  element in this list, the class toggle is applied to all elements.

I want to be able to click and unclick each letter to toggle the class change individually. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficulty is that in your case all list elements share the same scope, so when you set `isActive` there is no way to distinguish which one is actually should be active.

The simple solution to me is to isolate scope for every item. Maybe this is not nicest solution, but pretty simple with the help of very tiny directive:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in listItems">
            <a isolate ng-class="{'userActive': isActive, 'userInactive': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">L</a>
            <a isolate ng-class="{'userActive': isActive, 'userInactive': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">R</a>
            <a isolate ng-class="{'userActive': isActive, 'userInactive': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">J</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Where `isolate` directive is defined as:

```
app.directive('isolate', function() {
    return {scope: true};
});
```

Comment: plus1 way to go @dfsq

Answer (score 1):

you need to use three varaibles for ng-class, using one will reflect everywhere

```
<a ng-class="{'userActive': isActiveL, 'userInactive': !isActiveL}" ng-click="isActiveL = !isActiveL">L</a>
<a ng-class="{'userActive': isActiveR, 'userInactive': !isActiveR}" ng-click="isActiveR = !isActiveR">R</a>
<a ng-class="{'userActive': isActiveJ, 'userInactive': !isActiveJ}" ng-click="isActiveJ = !isActiveJ">J</a>
```

if you want to use only one varaible

```
<a ng-class="{'userActive': isActive==1, 'userInactive': isActive!=1}" ng-click="isActive=1">L</a>
<a ng-class="{'userActive': isActive==2, 'userInactive': isActive!=2}" ng-click="isActive=2">R</a>
<a ng-class="{'userActive': isActive==3, 'userInactive': isActive!=3}" ng-click="isActive=3">J</a>
```

Comment: there must be a better way... Consider that I might not know how many users my app will have or how many L, R and J variables I'll need. I can fall back on that solution in a pinch but I'd rather design it with more extensibility.

Comment: @amoeboar see updated answer, you can use one variable but youwill need to keep check for 1,2,3 in every case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in listItems">
        <a ng-class="item.isActive ? 'userActive' : 'userInactive'" ng-click="item.isActive = !item.isActive">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```