# AngularJs - unable to set ng-class to a specific element according to a server response

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm using `ng-class` in my app to set some styles on the fly to a clicked element, depending on the response from the server. So far, I'm only able to set the style to all elements at once (I guess due to same scope?), generated by `ng-repeat`, instead of only the clicked one.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242482/angularjs-toggle-class-for-only-one-element-ng-class-and-ng-click), but was unable to combine that with a dynamic response from the server.

The scenario is a follows, unknown amount items with two buttons in each, `publish` and `unpublish`. The style is set only to the `publish` button, according to user selection (`unpublish` removes something from the db and sets `btn-publish` class to this button, while click on `publish` adds item to the db and sets the `publishedBtn` class to the `publish` button).

EDIT: I added a "simulation" of the behavior, jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtyvgo98/).
HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <button class="btn btn-publish" ng-click="publish(item.id)" ng-class="(pub==true) ? 'publishedBtn' : 'btn-publish'">publish</button>
  <button class="btn btn-publish" ng-click="unPublish(item.id)">unpublish</button>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.publish = function(postId) {
  $http({
    url: "someUrl",
    method: "POST",
    headers:{'someHeader'},
    data: $.param({publish: postId})
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if ($.trim(data) == "published") {
      $scope.pub = true;
      console.log("published");
    }
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}


$scope.unPublish = function(postId){
        $http({
        url: "someUrl",
        method: "POST",
        headers:{'someHeader'},
        data: $.param({unPublish:postId})
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if($.trim(data)!="published"){ 
            $scope.pub = false;
            console.log("un-published");
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how `ng-class` works. If you want to use it correctly, your HTML should look like:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="publish(item.id)" ng-class="{'publishedBtn': pub,'btn-publish': !pub}">publish</button>
```

**EDIT**
Now that I understand the problem better, here is a complete solution.
The reason all your publish buttons got changes is the one you guessed: you save the `pub` value on the scope. The solution is easy: save it on the item.
Consider this solution:
HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <button class="btn btn-publish" ng-click="publish(item)" ng-class="{'publishedBtn': item.pub,'btn-publish': !item.pub}">publish</button>
  <button class="btn btn-publish" ng-click="unPublish(item)">unpublish</button>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.publish = function(item) {
  $http({
    url: "someUrl",
    method: "POST",
    headers:{'someHeader'},
    data: $.param({publish: item.id})
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if ($.trim(data) == "published") {
      item.pub = true;
      console.log("published");
    }
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}


$scope.unPublish = function(item){
    $http({
    url: "someUrl",
    method: "POST",
    headers:{'someHeader'},
    data: $.param({unPublish:item.id})
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if($.trim(data)!="published"){ 
        item.pub = false;
        console.log("un-published");
    }
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}
```

See [improved fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k3um278/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems the style is sill applied to all elements.

Comment: Any way to create a demo (plunker/fiddle) to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Any tips\thoughts on how I should plan and design my code for the next time? AND is it possible to use `item.publish` inside the `ng-class` to apply the class on page load?